# curl gives response 200 but openssl s_client gives timeout after ssl handshake

Tags: curl, openssl, amazon-elb

I'm having an issue with getting response from ELB using openssl package.

Curl works well:

```html
$ curl -iv https://example.com/isActive
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (*.*.*.*) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* ALPN/NPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

> GET /isActive HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
HTTP/1.1 200 
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-getMessageType, accept, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-getMessageType, accept, x-requested-with
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
< Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
< Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 12:48:26 GMT
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 12:48:26 GMT
< Content-Length: 6
Content-Length: 6
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
ACTIVE
```

But when I'm using openssl package and trying to type in any HTTP Method i'm getting timeout error:

```html
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3205 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 0CED79628CFCF32462EEF5086AD38
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 2ADB0E064422DFBAAAF704B17A1D3
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1540472141
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)

GET /isActive
HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Content-Length:0
Connection: Close

closed
```

What could cause this issue? I also tried to pass keep-alive header but still no luck. Thanks!

Comment: You have to send a *valid* HTTP request. `GET /isActive HTTP/1.0` and probably a `Host:` header too.  What is the purpose of this exercise?  If you just want to check the cert and automatically close the connection, use `true | openssl s_client ...`.

Comment: It's used in some monitoring system like a healthcheck for specific path /isActive
I tried to use headers you mentioned, also added keep-alive header but still no luck. Thanks for trying help.

Comment: Again, you are getting the timeout because the server does not consider your request complete.  `GET /isActive HTTP/1.0` followed by Control-J, twice, or Control-J, Control-M, Control-J, Control-M should result in a response.  HTTP header *lines* are terminated with `\r\n` (Control-J, Control-M) and this is repeated to signal end of headers.  Keep-Alive is not relevant.  You are getting a timeout because you are not sending a complete, valid HTTP request.

Comment: No luck, still timeout. But if i'm just pressing Control-J or Control-M or Enter without any input, i'm getting HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
closed
So if i do the same for google.com for example i see response. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to pass -crlf to the command:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect example.com:443
```